# Как вытащить изображение из инфоблока

Tags: php, битрикс

Как вытащить изображение из инфоблока? На снимке сам инфоблок. Свойство картинки называется BUTTON.

[image]

Примерный код:

```
<table width="300px" border="1">
<?
CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');
$arSelect = Array("NAME", "ID", "PROPERTY_BUTTON");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>115, "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize"=>50), $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
{
  $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
  ?>

        <tr>
            <td>
            <?=$arFields['PROPERTY_BUTTON_VALUE']// Видимо не правильно я указал, знаю, что просто текст вытаскивается ['PROPERTY_BUTTON_VALUE']['TEXT'], а вот как картинку дергать?> 
            </td>
        </tr>

<?}?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Ребята решение найдено!***

вместо:

```
<?=$arFields['PROPERTY_BUTTON_VALUE']?>
```

пишем:

```
<img src="<?=CFile::GetPath($arFields['PROPERTY_BUTTON_VALUE']);?>" />
```

Comment: Все доброго дня! подскажите где и как применить данный скрип? возникла потребность скачать все фото из инфоблока

Comment: @user385960 смотря из какого места вы собираетесь вызвать метод получения фото. В любом месте кода можете сделать этот вызов. Эточните вопрос, что именно у вас не получается?